# Three-Way Anova in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I am trying to do a three-way ANOVA in R Studio (the latest version) and I can't seem to figure out the code that will allow me to do this. I am trying to see if there is a significant difference between the three variables "Latitude May", "Latitude June", and "Latitude July". I have attached a sample of what my data looks like:

```
Latitude May        Latitude June        Latitude July
47.87927            47.72927             46.987292
46.97263            45.26472             46.6289173
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
install.packages(c("ggplot2", "ggpubr", "tidyverse", "broom", "AICcmodavg"))
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(AICcmodavg)
setwd("~/Desktop/Files Needed for ANOVA and T-tests")
read.csv("All Whales Distribution (Updated) Latitude ANOVA.csv")
data<-read.csv("All Whales Distribution (Updated) Latitude ANOVA.csv")
summary(data)
three.way <-aov(Latitude May, Latitude June, Latitude July, data = data)
```

This last line is where I am missing a character, one of which I am not sure of what it is. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: That last code line of yours suggests, to me at least, that you perhaps don't really know your way around R at all.
Have you consulted the manual page of the `aov` function? You could run `help(aov)`. Otherwise I really dont know where to start. What did you want that aov call to return?

Comment: There are a few issues with your code. The column names in the CSV have spaces. If you read that file using `read.csv` the spaces may have been replaced by periods. `aov()` requires a formula - something like `outcomeVar ~ Var1 * Var2 * Var3`. Other things to note: you don't need to load `ggplot2` if you load `tidyverse` (it's included) and the use of `setwd()` is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Hi all, I am very new to R so please don't mind the stupid questions! I am just looking to do a 3 way anova between those three variables to see if there is a significant difference between the latitudes. What would my code be? I am not sure what the 'outcomeVar' would be here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your data needs to be tidied first. Reorganize your dataset as:

```
Month Latitude
May 47.87927   
May 46.97263 
June ...
June ...
July ...
July ...
```

And then this is more like a one-way Anova:

```
myanova <-aov(Latitude ~ Month, data = data)
```

Comment: Hi Zihni Sinir, welcome to SO. While your suggestions offer some guidance, your answer is incomplete. Answers to questions like this need to be self-explanatory and reproducible. Please update your answer to include the packages required and the steps needed to 'tidy' the example data e.g. `tidyr:pivot_longer()` or similar. Also include the output from your `aov()`. Thanks